# Notepad++ is now really slow when search/replacing

Tags: notepad++

I've recently installed N++ 64-bit v7.8.5 on my Win10 machine and noted that it's now often incredibly slow when search/replacing strings. So slow that I have to often kill it and do my replacements in another editor. What's going on? How can I fix it?

The simplest example when I ran into this issue is when I tried to replace all sequences of 3 spaces with 2 spaces. The file was less than 1000 lines long. In case it makes a difference:

1. I have many document tabs open but I was only searching in one of them
2. Even though I didn't really have to for this particular example, I used the "Extended" search option, and my "Warp text" checkbox was checked.

Comment: Try recent updates ans check if the issue persists.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That would be my last resort. This is my work computer and getting our IT dept to install anything is kind of PITA. Plus I checked release notes on https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads for the 3 newer releases and none of them mention anything about resolving this issue. So I want to first try fixing the version I have.

Comment: Well, how much lines are on the file?

Comment: Not sure how strict your IT policies are, but if it allows portable apps, you could test if the newest version resolves your issue. [On the download page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.8/) you can download any non-installer version (zip, 7z) extract it on your desktop and run notepad++ from there.

Comment: Also, details on what you're trying to find/replace helps. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1568295/edit) your question to include details like number of lines, filesize of the file you're trying to replace, installed plugin's, etc...
No need to pre-face it with **Update**, or **Edit** or something like that, just naturally edit your question as if you're writing it for the first time (but with the knowledge you got from the comments). Thanks!

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan updated

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke updated. I don't think the policy allows portable apps

Comment: Thanks for the update. Regarding `I don't think the policy allows portable apps`. Can you please try?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I downloaded and ran the latest release without installing. Opened the same file as before (but only that one, no other tabs), and did the space search/replace. It worked. I expected it to run faster (1000 lines, the replace run replaced about 55000 instances). I'll assume this is the fix and will ask my IT to run the full installer. Hopefully that'll be it. Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IT policy allows for it you can download [the latest version](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.8/) as a portable application (zip, 7z) and check if this solves the slowness.

Answer (score 6):

I have same issue on x86 on all versions since some point.

Now I finally done some experiments and found that slow search/replace happens when "XML Tools" plugin are installed. When I removed this plugin, replace became fast again.

In my case it is Notepad++ 7.9 (32-bit) and XML Tools 3.0.3.3.
Update to XML Tools 3.0.4.3 solves this problem.
( https://github.com/morbac/xmltools/issues/37 )

So if this didn't help I suggest repeat my experiments:

1. Try disabling all (non-default) plugins.
2. Try downgrading to older versions (using portable builds easier).

Comment: This should be approved answer in my view.
That 3.0.3.3 version of XML tools introduced this bug which was fixed in later versions.
I update Notepad++ as soon as new version is available but newer versions have not fixed that slow text search/replace functions. Upgrading XML tools solved that issue. I was using x64 version but it looks like the bug was on both x86 and x64 editions.

Comment: Same here, and the difference is ridiculous. It would take 3 seconds per line on o big CSV file where I've made a regex to convert date formats. Removing the plugin took 2 seconds for 30k lines. Updating XMLTools to v3.1.1.10 worked also.